# How can we append numbers to the duplicate names, and upload them in the main excel file with pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

I have an excel file. I want to find if there are any duplicate values in a column and if there is, the numbers (1,2..) should be appended in the string. How can I do it with pandas?

I was able to do find what are the duplicate values but do not know how to change those strings. What must be added to the code herewith?

```
master_location='C:/Users/Elite/Desktop/'+user+'/MeterMasterReport.xlsx'
require_col=[1,6,10,12,15,17]
master=pd.read_excel(master_location,header=3,usecols=require_col)
df=pd.DataFrame(master)
a=df.sort_values(by=['CIRCLE','DIVISION','SUBDIVISION','SECTION'])
duplicate=a[a.duplicated('NAME')]
for a in duplicate['NAME']:
    final_name=a+'1'
    print(final_name)
```

I got this result which is the duplicate names with numbers at the end like *KARNE1, BAGWA1,..... How can I update them in the main sheet?

```
KARNE1
BAGWA1
LEKNATH1
POKHARA1
BINDABASHINE1
ROYAL1
```

What would be the code for it? Can you please help me go ahead?

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not want suffix for names that are not duplicated, you can group your data by `NAME` and get two series
1) `suffix:` Instance number of a name (which will be your suffix)
2) `repeats:` Instances of duplication (identifier to add suffix or not)

Using `repeats`, you can decide whether to add `suffix` to the NAME

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({'NAME':['A','A','B','C','D','D'],
                'DIVISION':['a','b','c','d','e','f'],
                'SUB_DIVISION':['m','n','o','p','q','r']
                })

name_groups = df.groupby('NAME')['NAME']
suffix = name_groups.cumcount()+1
repeats = name_groups.transform('size')

df['NEW_NAME'] = np.where(repeats > 1, df['NAME'] + suffix.map(str), df['NAME'])
```

`NEW_NAME` is then a string concatenation of `NAME` and `suffix` where `repeats` is greater than one

Result:

```
df : 

  NAME DIVISION SUB_DIVISION NEW_NAME
0    A        a            m       A1
1    A        b            n       A2
2    B        c            o        B
3    C        d            p        C
4    D        e            q       D1
5    D        f            r       D2
```

Comment: thank you. But I do not want any numbers at the end until they are repeated. How can it be done?

Comment: Updated the answer: `repeats` in addition to `suffix` should allow you to have a conditional string concatenation.